# SimpleITK: How to translate mask based to default origin, spacing, direction

Tags: python, arrays, image-segmentation, medical, simpleitk

I am doing a project on medical image segmentation and having trouble aligning masks and lesions. I am trying to use the `SimpleITK` package to correct the masks (`.nrrd`) files based on their metadata. I am assuming that all the images have the same metadata(spacing, direction, origin), indicated by the default constants in the code.

The appended code does not do what I want -- instead of moving the mask a small amount, it just sets every element in the mask to zero. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? Is `ResampleImageFilter` the transform I need?

I am also ok with solutions that use other libraries.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

DEFAULT_DIRECTION = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
DEFAULT_SPACE = (1., 1., 1.)
DEFAULT_ORIGIN = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

def projectImage(image, mask):
    image.SetSpacing(DEFAULT_SPACE)
    image.SetDirection(DEFAULT_DIRECTION)
    image.SetOrigin(DEFAULT_ORIGIN)

    resample = sitk.ResampleImageFilter()
    resample.SetReferenceImage(image)
    resample.SetInterpolator(sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor)
    resampledimg = resample.Execute(mask)
    return resampledimg


image = np.load('SAM.npy') # (54, 512, 512)
mask_sitk = sitk.ReadImage('SAM.nrrd')
sitk_image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(image)  # Transform fails even if I transpose image.
alignedmask = projectImage(sitk_image, mask_sitk)
alignedmasknpy = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(alignedmask).T  # (54, 512, 512)
mask_arr = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(mask_sitk)  # (512, 512, 54)
imgnpy = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(sitk_image).T   # (54, 512, 512)
print(alignedmasknpy.max())  # 0
print(mask_arr.max())  # 1
```

Comment: resample needs to be told how to resample - what transform is required. If your data is not at an origin (0,0,0) it doesn't know how to move the image into the space you've specified. As a result, it doesn't generate a result. You need to provide a Transform - see here https://simpleitk.github.io/SPIE2018_COURSE/images_and_resampling.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't actually intend to [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration) images.

If I need to wrangle images into the same space I simply use the [`CopyInformation()`](https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1Image.html#afa8a4757400c414e809d1767ee616bd0) function.

For example:

`mask.CopyInformation(image)`

This should remove the need to hardcode image spaces aswell.